# Touch event handling on Canvas in WeChat mini-program

Tags: canvas, touch, wechat

I created a 3D simulation WeChat mini-game.
For some reason, I should re-implement it as a WeChat mini-program.
So I created a canvas on `index.wxml`.

```html
<!--index.wxml-->
<view class="container">
  <canvas type="webgl" id="myCanvas" style="height: 750rpx; width: 750rpx;"></canvas>
</view>
```

I tried to capture the touch event on the canvas as I used to in HTML5.

```js
const app = getApp()

Page({
  onReady() {
    const query = wx.createSelectorQuery()
    query.select('#myCanvas').node().exec((res) => {
      const canvas = res[0].node
      canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        console.log(getTouchPos(canvas, e))
      }, false);
    })
  }
})
```

But I got an error message and mini-program didn't run.

```sh
VM379:1 thirdScriptError
canvas.addEventListener is not a function;at SelectorQuery callback function
TypeError: canvas.addEventListener is not a function
```

On mini-game, it was done by `wx.onTouchStart()` or sth like that.

**How can I get Touch events on canvas in WeChat mini-program?**

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of my code so that I could listen to the touch event.

```html
<!--index.wxml-->
<view class="container">
  <canvas
    type="webgl"
    id="myCanvas"
    style="height: 750rpx; width: 750rpx;"
    bindtap="onTap"
    ></canvas>
</view>
```

```js
// index.js
Page({
  onReady() {},
  onTap: (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }
})
```

Although I solved this issue, **more answers and comments are welcomed.** For example:

- a detailed explanation about the difference between HTML5 canvas and WeChat mini-program canvas (not WeChat mini-game canvas
- other straightforward or a more intuitive way for touch event handling